# Why does a javascript with sourcemap not show up as a .ts file in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typescript

I am using Typescript and I am compiling to javascript with inline sourcemaps. Here's an example of my javascript file:

```
var AccessHomeController = (function () {
    function AccessHomeController($scope) {
        this.$scope = $scope;
        $scope.home = this;
    }
    AccessHomeController.$inject = [
        '$scope'
    ];
    return AccessHomeController;
})();

//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,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
```

When I use the Chrome Developer tools and select "Enable Source Maps" and the look at the source files this is exactly what I see. All I see is the source of a javascript and the sourcemap details.

So how can I see the original .ts and how can the inline sourcemap help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use the Chrome Developer tools and select "Enable Source Maps" and the look at the source files this is exactly what I see.

Press CTRL+O in developer tools and type `.ts` you should be able to see `.ts` files.

Comment: I did this and I still cannot see anything other than a long list of .js files. A couple of questions: Do you see under Sources > Sources the typescript files in the list of files and folders? Also with your code are you using inline sourceMaps like I have? Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell me how you normally compile your .ts files to .js. Are you using some gulp plugin or have you tried any of the gulp plugins. I have had so many problems with them I am unable to find one that works the way I want.